# Maven plugin with only setters (instead of attributes)

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven plugin that wraps the lifecycle of an existing resource. Several properties, exposed on that resource, have to be exposed as configurable properties in the plugin configuration.

Let's suppose the resource exposes a "xyz" property. I would like, in my Mojo, expose a setter method like this:

```
public void setXyz(String xyz) { resource. setXyz(xyz); }
```

without having a corresponding

```
@Parameter 
private String xyz;
```

Does anybody know if there's a way to avoid the `@Parameter` or to indicate such declaration at method level? Something like:

```
@Parameter 
public void setXyz(String xyz) { 
    resource. setXyz(xyz); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no since the following annotation has only been assigned to a `FIELD` target (see the `@Target` annotation on the `@Parameter` annotation interface). See the javadoc [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html).

```
@Documented
@Retention(value=CLASS)
@Target(value=FIELD)
@Inherited
public @interface Parameter
```

[This](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) doesn't restrict you for using getter and setter methods anyway.